# Is there a rate limit for APIs hosted on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, rate-limiting

I'm hosting my API on Heroku (example endpoint: `https://some-api.herokuapp.com/some/request`). I'm not currently paying for any subscription on Heroku.

Is there a limit to the number of calls to this API that I can make, eg. per hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit on requests your application can receive. You should implement rate limiting in your own code.

Answer (score -1):

the limit seems to be 4500 calls per hour.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits

Comment: that's for the Heroku platform API limit. Applications aren't subject to this limit.

Comment: @JohnBeynon what is the difference? My guess is that those are api request specific to the platform and not the hosted application.

Comment: @3366784 The difference is that the Heroku Platform API limit refers to requests you do to the Heroku APIs, such as `heroku cli` commands. There is no limit on how many requests can come through your web app